# Android yandex geocode address

Tags: android, yandex-maps, yandex-api

In my app I want to decode raw address into coordinates. I do it like that:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.add("geocode", URLEncoder.encode(charSequence.toString(), "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

client.post(getApplicationContext(), "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
          Log.d("Yandex Geocode", "Success! Answer = " + new String(responseBody));
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
          Log.d("Yandex Geocode", "Failure :( Error = " + error.toString());
      }
});
```

However, this request can't reach server.

```
failed to connect to geocode-maps.yandex.ru/213.180.204.122 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Any suggestions why it't not working?

**EDIT**

It not working because yandex provides this api only for webapps and sites.
Found an ugly workaround for this. I'm loading a page in webview with this request url and getting raw text from response, from webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Android Geocoder. It is android native API.

**A class for handling geocoding and reverse geocoding.**

Comment: the problem is that Android Geocoder and Google geocoder works bad with russian addresses. Yandex maps api is the best for russian addresses